# What is actually the dot product of function and its total derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is a differentiable function from ℝ to the unit sphere $S^{n-1} \subset ℝ^n$, how we define the dot product of $f$ and $Df$?

Comment: The "dot product" only exists in a given coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a function $t\mapsto f(t)\in{\mathbb R}^n$ satisfying $$\langle f(t),f(t)\rangle=|f(t)|^2\equiv1\ .$$ Since
$${d\over dt}\langle f(t),f(t)\rangle=\langle f'(t),f(t)\rangle+\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle=2\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle$$
this implies
$$\langle f'(t),f(t)\rangle\equiv0\ .$$

Comment: Where does this last line come from?